# How to Auto Select all different Option in Similar many's Drop-Down boxes in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, select

[Please see this Image view that what i exactly want to do...](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0Btk6AnUQzdTDAwaWRyZmROWDg/edit?usp=sharing)

```
<%
for(;IteratorOfList.hasNext();)
{
String optionValue = IteratorOfList.next();
%>

<select id='1'>
<option value="Aunt">Aunt</option>
<option value="Brother">Brother</option>
<option value="Brother in law">Brother in law</option>
<option value="Cousin">Cousin</option>
<option value="Doughter">Doughter</option>
</select>
<%}%>
```

in this above code suppose for loop runs three times and hence we got three select boxes so my question is that how can i select options in all this three select box which i have fetched from the DATA BASE and all three values have binded in request object only just to select the three differnt values in these select....

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do

Comment: @EdgardLeal Leal please see my edited question

Comment: @sam describe how do you want to bind them

Comment: @RomanC C please you can see the link above in this link its a image view which describes easily that what i want to do

Comment: @sam : I updated the answer with the new jsfiddle.. hope it helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quite did not understand your question..but tried my best..

You want to populate a drop down list with the list of strings.

I am using `Jquery` to do this. 
Once you have the array of strings in your `javascript` you then iterate through the array and create the `<option>` elements with the array values and append it to the `select` box.

```
  $.each(relationsList, function(val, text) {
      $('#relationsDropDown').append( $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text) );
  });
```

According to the updated question.. I made the changes and here is the [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZEbX/4/)